# Semanage fcontext httpd_user_content add new context

Tags: linux, selinux

I have an issue because when I have added `semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_user_content_t '/home/[^/]+/((domains)|(public_html))(/.+)?'` this context doesn't work. For example I have created new user `useradd -m -d /home/test test` then I used command `mkdir domains` to create folder. Next I checked context this folder '`drwxrwxr-x. test test unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 domains`'.

When I used `restorecon -v /home/test1/domains` context works `restorecon reset /home/test/domains context unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0->unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0`. Someone can me explain why context doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

It is how it is supposed to work: you have to use restorecon on the folder once, then the newly created files will be labeled correctly.

If you want, there is two other ways of doing things, but it might be overcomplicated for what you want:

- write a type transition (lack of precision) / named type transition (lack of flexibility: no regex)
- use restorecond (there could be race conditions)

With restorecond, you could do what you want.
Although, based on your setup, it could be simpler to just use restorecon.

You can also take a look at [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/531431/selinux-canonical-way-of-automatically-applying-a-context-on-file-creation).